# Advice needed for scopes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I would like to connect this "JS" to Bugzilla (example: bugzilla.mozilla.org or landfill.bugzilla.org).

I started to learn JS language today and I would like to ask you:

1. How can I not do bad things in global scope?
2. How should I use functions (in `var` or not)?

```
quicksearch = document.getElementById('quicksearch_top');
comment = document.getElementById('comment');

severity = document.getElementById('bug_severity');
priority = document.getElementById('priority');

commit_top = document.getElementById('commit_top');
commit = document.getElementById('commit'); 

function focusonload() { 
// may be it should be
// in next function?

    function cursorfocus(s) {
        x = window.scrollX;
        y = window.scrollY;
        s.focus();
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
    }

    if (comment !== null) {
        cursorfocus(comment)
    } else {
        quicksearch.focus();
    }
}

function navigation(keypressed) { 

    keypressed = keypressed || window.event;

    function selectelement(w, select) {
        w.value = select;
    }

    keyCode = keypressed.keyCode || keypressed.which,
    kn = {
        enter: 13, 
        save: 83, 
        down: 40, 
        up: 38, 
        p1: 49, 
        p2: 50, 
        p3: 51, 
        p4: 52, 
        p5: 53, 
    };

    if (keypressed.altKey) {
        if (keyCode == nk.save && commit_top!==null){
            commit_top.click();
        }

        var key_str;
        if (priority!==null){
            switch (keyCode) {
                case kn.p1: key_str = "P1"; break;
                case kn.p2: key_str = "P2"; break;
                case kn.p3: key_str = "P3"; break;
                case kn.p4: key_str = "P4"; break;
                case kn.p5: key_str = "P5"; break;
            }
        }
        selectelement(priority, key_str);
        severity.focus();

    } else if (keypressed.ctrlKey) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case kn.enter:
                if (commit!==null&&comment.value!=="") {
                    commit.click();
                }
                break;
            case kn.up:
                if (quicksearch!==null) {
                    quicksearch.focus();
                }
                break;
            case kn.down:
                if (comment!==null) {
                    comment.focus();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

focusonload();
document.onkeydown = navigation;
// how to call this functions when page
// would be loaded at all (with window.onload)
```

Comment: typo: `if (keyCode == nk.save && commit_top!==null){` should be `kn.save` not `nk.save`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I not mess up the global scope?

You can use an IIFE ( Immediately Invoked Function Expression ) to surround your code and then assign all your variables with `var` <- Very important.

```
(function(){

  var quicksearch = document.getElementById('quicksearch_top');
  var comment = document.getElementById('comment');

  var severity = document.getElementById('bug_severity');
  var priority = document.getElementById('priority');

  var commit_top = document.getElementById('commit_top');
  var commit = document.getElementById('commit'); 

  //the rest of your code here

}());
```

> How should I use functions (in `var` or not)?

It really is up to you, at this point I prefer `function`.

*Other than that:*

You should use lowerCamelCasing, so

- commit_top -> commitTop
- quicksearch -> quickSearch
- selectelement -> selectElement

etc.etc

Your keycode map is very nice, keep it that way!

One last comment is that you should not use `document.onkeydown = navigation;`, there is a good chance that you will break something this way.

Try `document.addEventListener("keydown", navigation, true);` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices and for being answered.

Answer (score 3):

To add a couple of points to konijns answer;

You can remove the need for verbose switch statements with a `dict`:

```
var kn = {
    49: 'P1', 
    50: 'P2', 
    51: 'P3', 
    52: 'P4', 
    53: 'P5', 
};

...

var keyStr = kn[keyCode];
```

You can call a function when the page loads using the `onload` event:

```
window.onload = focusOnLoad;
```

Since it's only executed once `function cursorfocus(s)` may as well be inline, rather than a function declaration. The same with `selectElement()`.

I also like to put the larger block of code in my else statement. This makes it easier to read, and the flow feels better. Also avoid unnecessary variables, it's quite clear what this code means without `x` and `y`.

```
if (!comment) {
  quicksearch.focus();
} else {
    s.focus();
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY);
}
```

Finally, don't forget those `var` statements!

Comment: Why would you use an anon function`window.onload = function() {` for onload when you're just calling a single function? Also I on't think the `focusOnLoad()` function was specified as on load of window but rather on load of the script. Also the difference between your `kn` object and the OP's is that yours is in reverse. *(numbers to names rather than names to numbers)*

Comment: @JamesKhoury Whoops, good point. I got the `onload` requirement from the comments at the bottom. Quite true about the `kn` object, but since he's not really using the names for anything I deemed the object mapping more effective.

Comment: the `kn` object is used in detirmining the `keyCode`

Comment: @JamesKhoury Yes, but the **keys** in the `kn` object aren't used for anything, so they don't need to be words like `enter`, `save` and `down`, it's simple enough to understand without.